# Using puppet to ensure vagrant box is upgraded

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, apt

I'm using puppet to provision a vagrant box (Ubuntu in this case). After initially starting the vagrant box (`vagrant up`), running `apt-get upgrade` will list several updates. I would like to run these upgrades on the first boot, but am having trouble getting puppet to even run apt-get upgrade:

```
# run apt-get update
exec { "apt-update":
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
}

# run apt-get upgrade
exec { "apt-upgrade":
  command => "apt-get upgrade -y",
  path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin",
  require => Exec['apt-update'],
}
```

The following fails with:

```
err: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: apt-get upgrade -y returned 100 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/site.pp:34
```

**Additional research: ** one google groups post suggested the following which didn't help:

```
Exec { path => [ "/usr/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/local/bin" ] }
```

And I tried adding a call to `apt-get -f install -y` before as well. Neither worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the path settings turned out to be on the right track and this post helped me track down the last bit of how to fix this: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/1563/why-does-exec-fail-when-executing-directly-succeeds/

Essentially, `dkpg` was erroring out:

```
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable.
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable.
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-upgrade]/returns: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

When I add `/sbin` to the path for upgrade, it works.

```
exec { 'apt-upgrade':
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get --quiet --yes --fix-broken upgrade",
  logoutput => "on_failure",
  path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin",
  require => Exec['apt-update'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial apt-get update request to look something like this:

```
exec { 'apt-get':
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
    onlyif => "/bin/sh -c '[ ! -f /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin ] || /usr/bin/find /etc/apt/* -cnewer /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin | /bin/grep . > /dev/null'",
}
```

Then you can do:

```
# run apt-get upgrade
exec { 'apt-upgrade':
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -y",
  require => Exec['apt-update'],
}
```

Comment: It looks like "upgrade" still returns an exit code of 100. So I'm trying to track that down. That update command looks helpful, though.